# Is Active Directory required for a VPN?

Tags: windows-server-2008, active-directory, vpn

I hope someone can help. I'm currently setting up my first VPN on a Windows Server 2008 R2 box and every tutorial I've found says to configure Active Directory first. I've not actually done that before, either, so I was wondering if it was completely necessary?

Also, what type of VPN would you recommend? L2TP/IPSec or SSTP?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If RRAS is installed and configured on a machine that is not a member of the domain, it will use the local accounts database rather than Active Directory, the setup process is the same.

With regards to the protocol, they are both good options. Both make use of certificates, SSTP gives you the advantage that it uses port 443, which should mean you have minimal firewall issues. L2TP operates at the IP layer, whereas SSTP operates at the TCP layer, if that has any bearing on your choice.

Comment: Thanks for that. How do you create certificates without Active Directory, though? I really want to be messing around with AD as little as possible because this machine has to connected to another machine and I want the least amount of configuration issues possible. Thanks again

Comment: From my research it seems it ISN'T possible to have a VPN without AD CS installed, unless you want an unsecured VPN, of course. (That's not full AD, however, just the Certificate Server.)